# Intercept and modify commands in bash scripts

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

I have some scripts and some commands in the scripts are like this

`./executable arg1 arg2 .. argn`

I want to change the above command to

`LD_PRELOAD=/some/lib ./executable my_arg1 my_argn arg1 arg2 argn; some_other_command`

One way to change the scripts, but I don't want to do that, instead I want to intercept those commands, change those commands and run them. How can I do that?

Comment: Do you have permission to move the existing `./executable` to a new location?  If so, the answer is relatively easy.

Comment: Yes, I have the root access in system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, move the existing executable to a new location:

```
mv ./executable ./executable.original
```

Second, create a shell script in it place.  Place the following commands in a new file called `./executable`:

```
#!/bin/sh
LD_PRELOAD=/some/lib ./executable.original my_arg1 my_argn "$@"
some_other_command
```

The shell will replace the incantation `"$@"` with `arg1 arg2 argn` as supplied by the calling program.

Third, set the execute bit on your new file:

```
chmod a+rx ./executable
```

Answer (score 0):

in bash you can have funky function names, so this should do precisely what you want:

```
./executable() {
  LD_PRELOAD=/some/lib command ./executable my_arg1 my_argn arg1 arg2 argn
}
```

Of course it won't interccept `executable` or `/usr/bin/executable`